# How to calculate view-space position from screen-space position without matrix multiplication

Tags: shader, hlsl

I am calculating the view-space position from the screen-space position inside of multiple light- and post-process-shaders. My current code is restoring the position using the inverse of the projection matrix:

```c
float depth = depthBuffer.Sample(sampler, uv).x;
float4 temp = mul(float4(uv.x * 2 - 1, (1 - uv.y) * 2 - 1, depth, 1), inverseProjectionMatrix);
float3 viewSpacePosition = temp.xyz / temp.w;
```

As an optimization I would like to remove the matrix multiplication from my shader and restore the view-space position using variables like `aspect`, `near-clip` and `far-clip`.

Comment: How do you know it'd be faster to remove the matrix multiplication? GPUs are pretty much designed to do those, and it's only a few simple multiply-accumulates.

Comment: It is 16 multiplications of which only 5 are required (as the other 11 fields of a projection matrix are nulled out). The scene has a high amount of lights, all using the mentioned code in the pixel shader and it is also used in full screen effects like SSAO (multiple times per pixel). I don't know exactly how much this will affect performance, but the renderer is currently GPU bound and the code is so common I figured I should give it a try :)

Comment: Even a naïve vector-matrix multiplication is still only four vectorized multiply-accumulates, and GPUs generally have optimized paths for when it determines the matrix has a lot of zeroes (i.e. sparse vs. dense).

Comment: How can the GPU take an optimized path when it does not know about the zeroes prior to compilation? Also four MADs is half the cycles of my point light shader, and I am still interested in the math, even if the performance benefit is small.

Comment: @JensNolte In one cycle, the GPU hardware core can e.g. test all values in a row in parallel and perform a move rather than a dot product whenever it sees a single 1 and all other elements 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not say how you are creating the perspective projection matrix, which is key information. I am not a D3D expert.  Rather I know OpenGL.

So I can show you how to do this with the matrix that OpenGL `gluPerspective` produces.  It has the form:

[image: gluPerspective matrix]

This matrix is for OpenGL column vectors.  Your D3D code uses a row vector, so I'll assume the transpose.  For convenience rename the non-zero terms and take the inverse:

[image: gluPerspective simplified and inverted]

Inverting symbolically with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) (a nice tool for this sort of thing):

```
{{a,0,0,0},{0,b,0,0},{0,0,c,-1},{0,0,d,0}}^-1
```

We get:

[image: inverse matrix expression]

So if the point being multiplied is `[x y z 1]` as in your code, then the result you want is

```
[x/a y/b -1 (z+c)/d]
```

This is a 4d homogenous point.  To get back to 3d, divide through x,y,z by w:

```
[(1/a)ux  (1/b)uy  -u]  where u = d / (z+c)
```

The (1/a) and (1/b) terms can of course be computed in advance.  After that, you need one addition, one division, and four multiplications to finish the job.

This explanation could be off modulo some negative signs or other minor details due to differences between D3D and OpenGL coordinate systems that I'm unaware of.

Having said all this, I agree with the commenters who think this is not going to produce a meaningful speedup.